# Python: take specific rows from duplicated ones

Tags: python, for-loop, duplicates, append

I am lost in trying to solve the following problem: for every date which is also duplicated, I want to save the row which has the highest Value (from this group of duplicated dates).

For example this:

| date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09/29 | 10 |
| 09/29 | 15 |
| 09/29 | 12 |
| 09/30 | 5 |
| 10/01 | 25 |
| 10/02 | 20 |

Should look like this:

| date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 09/29 | 15 |
| 09/30 | 5 |
| 10/01 | 25 |

I tried with for-loops but without any results.

Comment: How is the data stored in your program? Add your code to the question in order to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df.groupby(by='date').max().reset_index()
print(df)
```

```
# before
    date  Value
0  09/29     10
1  09/29     15
2  09/29     12
3  09/30      5
4  10/01     25
5  10/01     20 

# after
    date  Value
0  09/29     15
1  09/30      5
2  10/01     25
```